# Credit risk data

Tags: market-data, credit-risk

I am trying to get historical data for credit risk and do some analysis on it as a school project. I thought CDX index might be a good proxy for typical credit risk data, but I am not sure. Typically what might be a good and also accessible set of data for credit risk of a financial institution.

Also, if CDX is a good proxy, where can I find historical data for it. I get nothing out of Bloomberg and Markit.com. Is it an extra on Bloomberg?

Comment: check out Markit, one of the biggest providers, they may have sample data sets. Otherwise its hard to impossible to come by free real-time data. http://www.markit.com/en/products/data/data.page

Comment: I confirm that MarkIt is the golden source.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

CDX **is** available from Bloomberg at no extra cost, though they do not (so far as I know) form a total-return series that takes rolls into account.  See, for example, `CDX HY CDSI S19 5Y PRC Corp` or Bloomberg ID `CXPHY519`.

Answer (score 1):

As others have noted, Markit is a great source for this.  For CDX in particular, they publish on a daily basis their ["Biggest Credit Movers"](http://www.markit.com/en/about/news/commentary/cds/cds.page) which includes CDX, iTraxx, iBoxx, Sovereign Credit improvement/deterioration, and Corporate credit improvement/deterioration.  Here is a [sample](http://www.markit.com/assets/en/docs/commentary/markit-movers/2011/BigMovers200313.pdf) report, which you can also sign up to have emailed to you every day.  Keep in mind that this list will only include the largest changes and not the widest spreads/riskiest credit, but for your purposes might prove to have all the data you need.

Also, they have pretty thorough documentation of their methodology, definitions, and [index components](http://www.markit.com/en/products/data/indices/credit-and-loan-indices/index-annexes/annexes.page?), which is a huge plus plus.